# Prove that linear operator A has a nonzero kernel.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

H is a separable Hilbert space, E is an inseparable Hilbert space, A is a continuous linear operator from E to the space L (H) of continuous operators on H with an operator norm. $A:E\to L(H).$ Prove that A has a nonzero kernel.

Please help

Comment: What is an irreversible operator?

Comment: @SahibaArora inverse operator

Comment: It might useful to consider using the Bounded Inverse Theorem.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I don’t understand how the theorem can help, because it says that if the operator is bijective, then the inverse operator exists.

Comment: My thinking here was that if $A$ is assumed to be injective, then $A$ is a bijection between $E$ and $A(E)$; hence $E$ and $A(E)$ are isomorphic by bounded inverse thm. But I guess then one has to check the completeness of $A(E)$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong This approach doesn't work even assuming completeness of $A(E)$. $L(H)$ is not separable and so even if $E$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $L(H)$, it is not clear that you get separability of $E$ for a contradiction. To make it clear that you shouldn't expect an argument like this to work at all, notice you don't use the Hilbert space structure of $E$ at all, so if correct your argument would work with $E = L(H)$ and $A$ the identity map. But this map clearly has $0$ kernel.

Comment: @RhysSteele Ah, yes, thank you for this correction. Yes, it was my mistake in thinking that $L(H)$ was separable; perhaps I was confusing it with the case of a weaker topology.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @RhysSteele From my teacher at the institute

Comment: Then what have you been learning about recently? If this is an exercise for which your instructor has a solution in mind then it is probably based on that material and that context would be useful to include in the question.

Comment: We went through spectral theory, unitary operators, though I think this exercise is not related to this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't miss an assumption? If $A$ is assumed to be a compact operator then this follows from results in spectral theory

Comment: Didn't miss. Can you give a link to this statement?

Comment: Id missed a detail which means the proof using spectral theory I wanted isnt applicable but actually, you dont even need spectral theory if $A$ is compact. Compact operators have separable range which is already enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: find a countable set of linear functionals $\ell_k$ in $L(H)^*$ which separate points, i.e. if $\ell_{k}(T)=0$ for all $k$ then $T=0$.  (It may help if you think of linear operators on $H$ as infinite-dimensional matrices.)  Now consider the adjoint map $A^* : L(H)^* \to E$.  Since $E$ is not separable, you can find some nonzero $x \in E$ which is orthogonal to all the $A^* \ell_k$.  Show that $Ax=0$.

At a more abstract level, the obstruction is that $L(H)^*$ is weak-* separable and $E^*$ is not.  If $A$ were injective then the image of $A^*$ would be dense, and in particular weak-* dense, and a continuous linear map from a separable TVS to a non-separable one can never have dense image.